# Create a FileReader from an XMLResponse?

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to create a `FileReader` (not a `Document`) from an `XMLResponse` like this :

```
    // Parse XML Response
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource inStream = new InputSource();
    inStream.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(XMLResponse));
    Document doc = db.parse(inStream);
```

But I don't know how to use the `InputSource` to create it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a `FileReader`, because the response may not be coming from a file. But, as it seems, you can obtain a `Reader`, which is the proper way to refer to readers.

If a method requires specifically a `FileReader`, the method is not designed properly.